# Crazy python behaviour

Tags: python, max

I have a little piece of python code in the server script for my website which looks a little bit like this:

```
console.append([str(x) for x in data])
console.append(str(max(data)))
```

quite simple, you might think, however the result it's outputting is this:

```
['3', '12', '3']
3
```

for some reason python thinks 3 is the max of [3,12,3]!

So am I doing something wrong? Or this is misbehaviour on the part of python?

Comment: What is crazy is you expecting `str(x)` to make a number.

Comment: Does [str(x) for x in data] output a new list, or modify the current one?

Comment: Martin: It makes a new one, the literal `[` and `]` can be a reminder, it is a new list just like `[1,2,3]` is.

Comment: I guessed that was the behaviour. However the code which generates the data list is supposed to generate a list of ints :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the character `'3'` is higher in the ASCII table than `'1'`. You are comparing strings, not numbers. If you want to compare the numerically, you need to convert them to numbers. One way is `max(data, key=int)`, but you might want to actually store numbers in the list.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, this worked - however it was meant to be a list of integers!

Comment: It can't be a list of integers if you explicitly convert them to strings using `str(x)` :)

Comment: Yes, but the data list is a list of integers, and then I cast them to strings and append them to the console, that doesn't affect the contents of data... does it?

Comment: No, integers are immutable, it can't change them anyway. You took the integers, created strings that textually represent the integers and added them to the console list. So the console now contains a list of strings. Then you took the maximum value (lexicographically), create a new string with the same value and added it to the list.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I actually only now realized you are getting the max of `data`. Ignore the previous comment. The behavior means that the list doesn't contain integers as you think.

Comment: It seems that everything points to something other than a list of integers, I wish I had a strongly typed language ;)

Comment: @Martin: Python IS a strongly-typed language. Strongly-typed or not is nothing to do with your problem. `str()` and `max()` operate as advertised on a wide variety of types. How do you imagine a strongly-typed language would help you in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I know very little Python, but you are taking the max of strings, which means that `'3..'` is greater than `'1..'`.